# Number of occurances of words in a text (along with similar word)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a function, that will spot how many times, different words occured in a text. The thing is, that I would like bundle together similar words (and nicknames).

I have this array of interesting words (that I manually have defined):

```
$interesting_words = [
  'test' => [
    'number_of_occurances' => 0,
    'connected_words' => [
        'TEST',
        'TESTER',
        'TESTING'
      ]
    ],
  'foobar' => [
    'number_of_occurances' => 0,
    'connected_words' => [
        'FOO',
        'FOOBAR',
        'BAR'
      ]
    ]
]
```

**Example text.**

> Lorem ipsum TEST sit amet, consectetur TESTER elit. Sed in turpis dui.
>   Maecenas venenatis  FOOBAR facilisis. Quisque dictum, diam consequat
>   mollis TESTING, orci tellus aliquet nisl, BAR  molestie FOO augue at
>   est. In TESTING vehicula lectus. Curabitur ac varius ligula. 
>   Pellentesque orci urdna.

**Desired output.**

```
Number of occurances for 'test': 4
Number of occurances for 'foobar': 3
```

Are there a smart way of doing this without having 1.000.000 for-loops?

I'm making the function in Laravel, if that's any help.

Comment: Explode string and use in_array() simple only one loop needed. and use array_count_values()

Comment: Well.. I have to explode the example text and iterate through them, - that's one for-loop. Then I have to, - for every word, iterate through the $interesting_words-array and use the `in_array()` (unless I'm mistaking), - that's two for-loops. It is very longs texts, - so if I have to go through 10000 words this many times: `count( $interesting_words )`, - then that's quite the calculation. Is that really the best way of doing it?

Comment: may be else you have to go through words array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_word_count && array_count_values,` to get all words occurrences and `strtolower` to make the search case insensitive when performance and only number of occurrences count :

```
$words=array_count_values(str_word_count(strtolower($str),1));
foreach($interesting_words as $index=>&$details){
    foreach($details['connected_words'] as $key=>$similar){
        $details['number_of_occurances'] += $words[strtolower($similar)];
    }
}           
print_r($interesting_words );
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [number_of_occurances] => 4
            [connected_words] => Array
                (
                    [0] => TEST
                    [1] => TESTER
                    [2] => TESTING
                )

        )

    [foobar] => Array
        (
            [number_of_occurances] => 3
            [connected_words] => Array
                (
                    [0] => FOO
                    [1] => FOOBAR
                    [2] => BAR
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by `explode` and `array_count_values` and to make it work In below example I removed `.` and `,`

```
<?php
$interesting_words = [
  'test' => [
    'number_of_occurances' => 0,
    'connected_words' => [
        'TEST',
        'TESTER',
        'TESTING'
      ]
    ],
  'foobar' => [
    'number_of_occurances' => 0,
    'connected_words' => [
        'FOO',
        'FOOBAR',
        'BAR'
      ]
    ]
];
$str = 'Lorem ipsum TEST sit amet, consectetur TESTER elit. Sed in turpis dui. Maecenas venenatis FOOBAR facilisis. Quisque dictum, diam consequat mollis TESTING, orci tellus aliquet nisl, BAR molestie FOO augue at est. In TESTING vehicula lectus. Curabitur ac varius ligula. Pellentesque orci urdna.';
$str = preg_replace('/[\.\,]/i','',$str);
$str = strtolower($str);
$str_arr = explode(" ",$str);
$str_occurance_counts = array_count_values($str_arr);
foreach($interesting_words as $k=>&$v){
  foreach($v['connected_words'] as $c=>$cVal){
    $v['number_of_occurances'] += $str_occurance_counts[strtolower($cVal)];
  }
}
print_r($interesting_words );
?>
```

[Live Demo Server1](https://eval.in/1055462)

[Live Demo Server2](https://3v4l.org/l4kIq)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$interesting_words = [
  'test' => [
    'number_of_occurances' => 0,
    'connected_words' => [
        'TEST',
        'TESTER',
        'TESTING'
      ]
    ],
  'foobar' => [
    'number_of_occurances' => 0,
    'connected_words' => [
        'FOO',
        'FOOBAR',
        'BAR'
      ]
    ]
];

$testCount=$interesting_words['test']['number_of_occurances'];
$foobarCount=$interesting_words['foobar']['number_of_occurances'];

$text="Lorem ipsum TEST sit amet, consectetur TESTER elit. Sed in turpis dui. Maecenas venenatis 
FOOBAR facilisis. Quisque dictum, diam consequat mollis TESTING, orci tellus aliquet nisl, BAR 
molestie FOO augue at est. In TESTING vehicula lectus. Curabitur ac varius ligula. 
Pellentesque orci urdna.";

$arr= explode(" ", $text);
$numberOfWords=count($arr);
for($i=0;$i<$numberOfWords;$i++)
{
    echo "<br/>";

    if(strpos($arr[$i],'TEST') !== false){
        $testCount=$testCount+1;
    }

    elseif(strpos($arr[$i],'TESTER') !== false){          

    $testCount=$testCount+1;
    }
    elseif(strpos($arr[$i],'TESTING') !== false){

    $testCount=$testCount+1;
    } 

   elseif(strpos($arr[$i],'FOO') !== false){

    $foobarCount=$foobarCount+1;
    }  

   elseif(strpos($arr[$i],'FOOBAR') !== false){

    $foobarCount=$foobarCount+1;
    } 

   elseif(strpos($arr[$i],'BAR') !== false){ 

    $foobarCount=$foobarCount+1;
    }   
}
echo "Number of occurances for 'test':".$testCount;
echo "</br>";
echo "Number of occurances for 'foobar':".$foobarCount;
```